# Stop Workmanager flutter when app is opened

Tags: android, flutter, periodic-task, flutter-workmanager

When app is in the background, I want workamnager to execute task to fetch data. When app is opened and active I want to stop it. How do I achieve such a behavior. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

use [WidgetsBindingObserver](https://medium.com/pharos-production/flutter-app-lifecycle-4b0ab4a4211a) to retrieve status of app lifecycle, inactive, pause, suspend you register the worker, resumed, you cancel the worker, [workmanager](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager):

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    //TODO add your worker action here
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Flutter Tutorial Lifecycle'),
      ),
      body: Center(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I already know about WidgetsBindingObserver, the problem is that workmanager cannot be paused or resumed. If I cancel a workmanager task when app is opened, then how can I reenable it when user leaves the app?

Comment: @anassnaoushi You will need to create a new task